# How to group the rows in excel using macros

Tags: excel, vba

This is what i need

[image]

i want to group the rows of above screen shot to below screen shot

[image]

Tried a lot using macro but not getting proper any one please help me out

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a pivot table?

Comment: @NikhilSurendran Can you also post the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with a pivot table. With a cell in your table selected, choose `Pivot Table` from the `Insert` tab. of the ribbon. Use the settings I show in this image. You can customize the pivot table to remove the Grand Total line.

[image]